# Hosting my own web server

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcp, web-hosting, nameserver

NOTE: I've changed the question to a more specific one

Hello All,

I'm looking forward to host my own web server on a local machine. I need your help in setting everything that I can't setup. Here is my network structure:

I have the below at the moment:

```
1- A Hostname currently linked to an active website which is not hosted locally.
2- I have a single machine that will work as a virtual environment and will host:
    A) Firewall - Free Edition (Network Protection and Segmentation)
    B) Web Server (Public Access)
        i- Host OS undecided yet (Windows Server 2013/Linux Ubuntu)
       ii- Server Type (WAMP/LAMP)
    C) File Server (Local Access)
    D) DHCP Server (Probably with the File Server or hosted on the Firewall)
3- A router is in place (Port forwarding will be enabled to send the traffic to the Firewall) - Router may be switched with a Cisco Router With Wireless Capabilities
4- A Cisco Switch
```

What I understand now is:

```
1- The server should be in the DMZ (Done by the firewall)
2- A NameServer should be found within the DMZ to point to my server
3- A DNS Server should be installed in the network (I think in the DMZ as well)
```

What I need help with:

```
1- Understand the reason of the NS and how to configure it
2- The basic configuration of the DNS Server to have my server up
3- Any other point that I have missed
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: repost? http://serverfault.com/questions/194452/requirements-to-build-a-web-server

Comment: What you are asking here is for a business model/plan, which we cannot give you.  If you are going to go into business providing services to people, you need to get investors and hire people who can answer these questions for you in a manner that makes economic sense for your company.

Comment: repost yes, also very general question. How huge is huge? Why are you building a server? It would probably be cheaper and certainly easyer to get a standard server from a hosting company that would come pre-installed with CPanel and all the other software you need. And even 24MB/s is far to slow for a server, most servers run at ether 100mb/s or 1gb/s. Not promotion, but I would check out LiquidWeb, they've always been awesome with our servers/sites and their support is probably the best around.

Comment: @samarudge, in defense of the OP, he's referring to Internet connection speed, not internal LAN speed.

Comment: @Holocryptic I've always worked on the assumption that 100mb/s internet connection was standard? Every server I've worked on has had 100mb/s connection (Most of my servers are from OVH or LiquidWeb).

Comment: @Samarudge - I get the feeling that this "server" would be placed under a desk somewhere in an office running a residential internet connection.

Comment: @Mark We've all been there =) (Just not for a production website)

Comment: @Samarudge, while I don't have my own vps experience to draw on, I'm pretty sure that's just the port speed that you're seeing, not the actual internet connection speed.  I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This question will be closed soon, for the following reasons:

1. Don't build your own server. It's not worth the hassle. I used to do this, years ago, and the cost was only marginally cheaper than buying one from Dell or HP, but the reliability was shit.
2. There is no one size fits all answer for your software requirements. We can't answre this for you. You need to decide which one you're most comfortable with, and are almost always a part of the application considerations, not the server considerations. If you don't know which one you want, then you're out of your depth.
3. Re your bandwidth, how long is a piece of string? Nobody can answer this. The only person that can even get close is you, based on guessing how many users you'll have and how much data you're going to send. And even then you'll just be guessing.
4. Re hosting, it sounds like you're out of your depth here, so I would strongly suggest just purchasing a reseller account through any pre-established, high quality hoster already. Your clients will never know the difference, but your life will be so much easier.

Comment: Hello Mark, I've changed the question to a better one .. Pending your answer

Comment: @sikas after 3 years I'm afraid your current question is no more on topic than the previous one. For starters, it's a different question so it should really have been asked as a new question. But it's still full of subjective answers, or things that are going to require an entire book to explain to you. Rather than approaching things in one large chunk, try breaking them down into small, individually tacklable issues. You seem to really need some education about how DNS and NS records work so I would start there.

Comment: I'm unable to post new questions! I get a message that the site is not accepting new questions from my account! This is why I was trying to clarify more in this question